# Twilio calling app bill deduction

Tags: android, twilio, stripe-payments, twilio-api

We are making three way calling android app - two participants are app user and third one is any phone number using TWILIO. We have implemented call feature , our call is being connected but question is
            We need to know on server end that who is the user who have started the call so that we can deduct bill from that person. AND secondly how can we deduct the bill after every specific time interval say three minute.
            Please any guideline / algorithm is appreciated.

P.S We are using stripe as a payment gateway and twilio for calling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering my question so that any one can get help with it.
I contacted to twilio support by email and getting following response:

You can determine who started the call by checking the timestamps for each call in the conference. The one with the earlier StartTime is the one who started the call.

We don't have any guidelines or algorithms for deducting from your customer's bill at specific intervals.

Comment: adding some source code, email reference would be +1